# Morse-Smale Complex, boundary on the number of segments by the number of critical points.

Tags: general-topology, morse-theory

I am looking for a known upper bound on the number of monotone regions of a Morse function by the number of its critical points in the interior of the manifold and on its boundary.

Here I try to give a motivation

Given a Morse function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, I look at the simple integral 
$\int_{(0,t)^N} e^{-f(x)^2}\nabla(f(x))dx$.
I would like to make a change of variables, thus I consider the number of monotonous regions of $f$ in $(0,t)^N$.

Suppose then that $\{A\}_i^{M}$ is the number of such a regions, then I have

$\int_{(0,t)^N} e^{-f(x)^2}\nabla(f(x))dx = \sum_{\{A_i\}}\int_{A_i} e^{-x^2}dx$

Having done that I am looking to get an upper bound on this sum by, say, $T(p,g)$

$\sum_{\{A_i\}}\int_{A_i} e^{-x^2}dx \leq T(p,g)$

Where $p$ is the number of the critical points in the interior of $(0,t)^N$ and $g$ is the number of the critical points on the boundary $[0,t]^N$ (that is the critical point of the restriction of $f$ to the boundary).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The term "monotonousness" of function  $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is not well defined, function can be monotonous in one coordinate but not the other.

Comment: Probably a better formulation of the question should be:  to find a bound on the number of regions for which the Jacobian of $f$ does not vanish, in every such a region the change of variables formula works.